# How to update the user's street address using the DocuSign Admin API

Tags: docusignapi

How do I update a user's street address using the DocuSign Admin API? I have searched the documentation and can't seem to find this anywhere:

[Admin API Reference](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/admin-api/reference/)

I have traced the HTTP calls that the Admin API UI uses, but unfortunately DocuSign uses v1 of the API for their UI, and only reference v2 in their documentation.

In the v1 API, if you update a user's street address you would get a POST like the following:

```
POST https://admindemo.docusign.com/organizationapi/management/v1/organizations/{organizationId}/accounts/{accountId}/users/{userId}/address
```

What is the equivalent in the v2 Admin API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the information that you and I both have right now, you cannot do that using the DocuSign Admin API.
You can, however, do this using the eSignature API.
[This endpoint](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/users/users/update/) :

```
PUT /restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/users/{userId}
```

Take both home and work addresses (though not sure where you can see them in the UI differently). Here is a JSON snippet that is part of the body for updating a user:

```
 "workAddress": {
    "address1": "sample string 1",
    "address2": "sample string 2",
    "city": "sample string 3",
    "stateOrProvince": "sample string 4",
    "postalCode": "sample string 5",
    "phone": "sample string 6",
    "fax": "sample string 7",
    "country": "sample string 8"
  },
  "homeAddress": {},
  "loginStatus": "sample string 22",
  "passwordExpiration": "sample string 23",
  "lastLogin": "sample string 24",
  "sendActivationEmail": "sample string 25",
  "customSettings": [
    {}
  ],
```

Comment: I found the same issue with Phone number - it is possible to import it through Admin Bulk APIs (CSV file), but for some reason it's not possible to update it when calling create/update for a single user. The workaround of using eSignature API has one big caveat, as given in DocuSign API description: "Note: Users can only access their own information. A user, even one with Admin rights, cannot access another user's settings." This is a really strange decision by DocuSign. I guess I'll have to use Bulk CSV APIs to add/update even a single user.

Comment: Please submit a new question. thanks

Comment: I got Phone working through Bulk CSV updates. Still, it's weird that it's missing from single-user updates in Admin API. I have collected a bunch of inconsistencies in API and documentation, but those are more like notes and not questions; not sure how to pass them to you.

Comment: send me an email to inbar.gazit@docusign.com

Comment: Can you please look also at this one? I collected some additional findings there. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73049411/problems-with-anonymizing-user-information-when-closing-their-membership